# onFormSubmit trigger difficulty

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

The script is supposed to run when data from a partially completed form is submitted, and fill the incomplete row with data from above.

I have replaced the trigger with onEdit and the code worked perfectly, however when formSubmit runs it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
function formSubmit()

 {
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var email_address = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var lastRow=sheet.getLastRow()
  var lastColumn=sheet.getLastColumn()
  var entries=sheet.getRange(lastRow,1,1,lastColumn)
  for(var i=1; i<=lastColumn; i++)
    {
      var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,i).getValues() 
      if(cell==0)
      {
        var previousCell=sheet.getRange((lastRow-1),i).getValues()
        sheet.getRange(lastRow,i).setValues(previousCell)
      }
    }        
  }
```

Comment: What triggers this code?

Comment: Its using the onFormSubmit installable trigger.

Comment: Submit a Form, and then in the script editor click the "View" menu and choose the "Execution Transcript" menu item.  The time stamps should indicate whether the function ran or not. You can also use `Logger.log('it ran')` and view the logs to see if anything was printed to the log.

Answer (score 1):

In this section:

`var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,i).getValues() 
      if(cell==0)
      {`

cell is an array and should be written like this:

`var cell=sheet.getRange(lastRow,i).getValues() 
      if(cell[0][0]==0)
      {`

You might want to review the use of getValues() and consider what is returned.

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

You should debug this code as described by Alan Wells by submitting the form yourself.

Comment: I took your suggestions, and the script is running. However when I submit a incomplete form nothing happens when it should be filling up.

Comment: Do you still get the trigger?

Comment: @MasonSuess be sure to have the trigger working, i tested the code with the correction Cooper did and it worked as you intend.